# Prove a function could be written as a power series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose $S(z)=\sum a_n z_n $ has radius of convergence $>0 $, $a_0\not= 0$, prove that the function:
$$f(z)=\dfrac 1 {S(z)}$$ can be developed into power series at 0.

I don't have an idea of the condition, any help?

Thanks~

Comment: $f$ is holomorphic in a neighborhood of $0$, and holomorphic functions in the plane are analytic.

Comment: @user363464  I don't know why f is holomorphic?

Comment: by the chain rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by long division, or by multiplying both sides by $S(z)$ and discovering the coefficients required.

For example, if $$\sum x_n z^n \sum a_n z^n = 1$$
then we must have:

- $x_0 = \frac{1}{a_0}$ by considering the $z^0$ coefficient;
- $x_1 a_0 + x_0 a_1 = 0$ by considering the $z^1$ coefficient, so we can extract $x_1$ without any further division by anything except $a_0$;
- $x_2 a_0 + x_1 a_1 + x_0 a_2 = 0$ by considering the $z^2$ coefficient, so we can extract $x_2$ without any further division by anything except $a_0$;
- repeat inductively.

This constructs a power series; it trivially converges at $0$ because the first coefficient is $\frac{1}{a_0}$. This power series is $\frac{1}{S(z)}$ by just multiplying out the product of the two and obtaining $1$.